# Reset a "prevent download policy" for Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, file-download

I am developing something where the user can download an autogenerated PDF (using PDFMake). It worked OK until I accidently clicked "*prevent downloads from this site*" (or something similar, cannot remember). So now chrome simply does not respond to my downloads on http://localhost:9000, which makes it really impossible to debug. It works very well and as expected for example in FireFox.

How do I reset a "download policy" (in lack of a better or more correct term) in Chrome? I really cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be visible in the website's "info panel" (click the leftmost icon in address bar).

If not, visit *Settings → Content Settings → Automatic downloads* at:

```
chrome://settings/content/automaticDownloads
```

Comment: Thats it! `http://localhost:9000` was listed under "block".  Exactly what I hoped to figure out :)